# How to run OGR in ArcGIS Scripts?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, gdal, ogr

When I run my script outside ArcGIS it works because during execution script uses a GDAL and OGR modules from osgeo. When I use script as a tool in ArcGIS it does not work. In PySripter I can import all modules and it work. In Python Window in ArcGIS I cannot import because I get this error:

> Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 2) 
>   import ogr
>   Runtime error 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\osgeo\ogr.py", line 26, in 
>       _ogr = swig_import_helper()
>     File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\osgeo\ogr.py", line 22, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_ogr', fp, pathname, description)
>   ImportError: DLL load failed:

In the case when I import  gdal in ArcGIS Python Window I do not get this error.
How to force arcgis to import ogr and use it in ModelBuilder or Script??
I check a lot of solutions includin reinstallation, changing and adding environment variables. I checked :

1. http://pythongisandstuff.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/installing-gdal-and-ogr-for-python-on-windows/
2. http://www.wildsong.biz/index.php/Running_GDAL_scripts_in_ESRI_Model_Builder

and I still do not have a good solution. Any idea?

UPDATE:
I also try use direct importing in my script:
import imp
ogr = imp.load_source('ogr', 'c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\ogr.py'
and I get the same error. If I use this method in standalone script it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've gotten this working on my 10.1 system, at least somewhat (I can run `import ogr` from the ArcGIS python window and it appears to be working).

First I attempted to get my system as clean as possible. I uninstalled previous versions of GDAL (from OSGeo4W). I do still have PostgreSQL+PostGIS which has it's own version of GDAL, but I can't uninstall that (I need it).

Secondly, it looks like ArcGIS's python is located at a different folder on my system (it's in C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\Python27\ArcGIS10.1, not C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1). This is likely due to my 10.1 environment being a fresh install vs. an upgrade or something.

I used the GDAL installers from [this page](http://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1600-gdal-1-11-mapserver-6-4.zip). Specifically:

- [GDAL Core](http://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1600-gdal-1-11-mapserver-6-4/gdal-111-1600-core.msi)
- [FileGDB Plugin](http://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1600-gdal-1-11-mapserver-6-4/gdal-111-1600-filegdb.msi) (You probably want this)
- [Python 2.7 Bindings](http://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1600-gdal-1-11-mapserver-6-4/GDAL-1.11.2.win32-py2.7.msi)

I then setup the following environment variables:

- `PATH`: Added `;C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL` to the end. This resolved the DLL load error for me.
- `GDAL_DRIVER_PATH`: set to `C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdalplugins`
  (to get the FileGDB stuff to work)
- `GDAL_DATA`: set to `C:\Program
  Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal-data` (to get reprojection and other projection
  related stuff working)

[image: OGR in ArcGIS 10.1]