# How to programmatically delete all inner rings of a polygon layer?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, polygon

I have many polygon layers, each layer containing many polygons with inner rings. I know that you can delete a ring manually with QGIS (Edit -> Delete ring). I need the python equivalent to automatically process all my polygon layers.

Answer (score 6):

This blog posts tells how to do it with SQL in PostGIS http://geospatial.commons.gc.cuny.edu/2013/11/04/filling-in-holes-with-postgis/

Spatialite has also ExteriorRing function http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html so you do not need to have PostGIS installed. Is it necessary for you to do the job with python inside QGIS? The SQL looks like this:

```
UPDATE my_spatial_table t
SET geom = a.geom
FROM (
    SELECT gid, ST_Collect(ST_MakePolygon(geom)) AS geom
    FROM (
        SELECT gid, ST_NRings(geom) AS nrings, 
            ST_ExteriorRing((ST_Dump(geom)).geom) AS geom
        FROM my_spatial_table
        WHERE ST_NRings(geom) > 1
        ) s
    GROUP BY gid, nrings
    HAVING nrings > COUNT(gid)
    ) a
WHERE t.gid = a.gid;
```

Answer (score 3):

QGIS offers a tool called `Delete holes` that you can call via Python in this way:

```
import processing
vLayer = iface.activeLayer() # Select the layer in QGIS layer tree before calling this
outPath = "/path/to/output.shp"    
processing.runalg( "qgis:deleteholes", vLayer, outPath )
```

You could iterate through QGIS layers to run such tool on your polygon layers.

You could also access the source code of the tool to see how it works: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/release-2_14/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/DeleteHoles.py Note that the algorithm will change in QGIS v3.0, since there'll be a new `geometry().removeInteriorRings()` method: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/DeleteHoles.py

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable using Python, including ArcPy... Try this...

You can read the shapefiles using:

Step 1:

```
import shapefile # Required plugin is PyShp
sf = shapefile.Reader("Path to shapefile...")
```

'sf' will now contain your shapefile information.

Step 2:

Use ArcPy to find the intersection of polygons. If the interior polygons intersect the larger polygon (which they obviously will), delete the shape.

More information about PyShp could be found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshp).

More information of ArcPy can be found [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000070000000), including about the Intersection function

Comment: for arcpy, you'll need an ArcGIS licence.

Comment: Of course.. It can be done, without using ArcPy too.. U can use [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) or GDAL/OGR bindings too.. See this [Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90055/how-to-find-if-two-polygons-intersect-in-python)

Comment: The question do not mention that holes are separate interior polygons so I believe that they are only inner rings in the big polygons.

Comment: Yes... That clarifies the problem... If I understand correctly - A polygon with internal rings (input) needs a complete polygon without rings (output). Right?

Comment: That's correct Akhil - I specifically wanted to do it using python and PyQGis to integrate the functionality within one of my scripts. I think I'll manage thanks to all of your answers, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

shapely can do this by simply removing the `.interiors` of a the polygon.

Here is a complete example for removing the interiors of the first geometry of the the first feature of a geojson, assuming it's a *valid* `Polygon`:

```py
from shapely.geometry import mapping, shape, Polygon

def load_first_feature(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        root = json.load(f)
        if "features" in root: # collection case, take first
            assert len(root["features"]) == 1
            root = root["features"][0]
        return shape(root["geometry"]

def noholes(path):
    holy = load_first_feature(path)
    assert(isinstance(holy, Polygon))
    poly = Polygon(holy.exterior.coords)
    with open('noholes.geojson', 'w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(mapping(poly)))

noholes('polygon-with-hole.geojson')
```

Sample input/output

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": { "name": "union-with-holes" },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [ [ 7, 47 ], [ 2, 49 ], [ 6, 50.6 ], [ 6, 51 ], [ 7, 51 ], [ 8, 51 ], [ 8, 48 ], [ 6, 48 ], [ 7, 47 ] ],
            [ [ 5, 49 ], [ 6, 48 ], [ 6, 50 ], [ 5, 49 ] ]
        ]
    }
}
```

```
{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.0, 48.0], [7.0, 47.0], [2.0, 49.0], [6.0, 50.6], [6.0, 51.0], [7.0, 51.0], [8.0, 51.0], [8.0, 48.0], [6.0, 48.0]]]}
```