# Deleting lines in polygon shapefile using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, line

I have a [polygon shapefile](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10yWB0q8b73eXGEA6YW3II6fNMSmu3nUJ?usp=sharing).  After dissolving a few polygons I got some unrequired lines inside one of the polygons that I couldn't delete. When using the vertices tool the lines don't show and separate vertex that I can use to delete it.

Any ideas?

The green highlight is the lines that I want to delete using QGIS.

[image]

Comment: Note that polygon boundaries are composed of closed linestring loops. There is no line to delete, though there might be a common boundary to dissolve.

Comment: I already dissolved the polygons, and these two lines occurred after dissolving. my problem is similar to this problem, but couldn't solve it using any of the methods they mentioned https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155931/removing-lines-from-inside-polygon-in-qgis

Comment: I can't tell from your image but if use the split part editing tool or multipart to singlepart processing tool do you get polygons separated by what appears to be the line?  If so you likely have a very small gap between the edges of the adjacent polygons.  In an edit session zoom in and snap the vertices at the ends of each together.  To preserve topology make sure the other adjacent polygons vertices there are also snapped.  You might instead run a v.clean with a snap tolerance sufficient to make the boundaries coincident.  Then you can merge them.

Comment: @johns I have added the required shapefile to be able to edit it, as I tried your suggestions but none of them worked. I am new in qgis, so please some detailed solutions will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only two gaps, the easiest is to start editing, manually digitize a polygon covering the gap, merge it with the big one:

[image]

Comment: is it possible for you to do the edit on the attached file? as I am trying to follow the same steps but I get this error https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jzrxFOHlJJ9a3CgjJuERduLXMM-0TiKN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Try Fix Geomtries