# Installing GDAL Python bindings on Windows

Tags: python, gdal, windows, osgeo

This has been addressed before ([Installing GDAL with Python on windows?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/how-to-install-gdal-with-python-on-windows)), but I wanted to bring the question up again,

1. to see if anybody has come up with a better method in the last 5
   years, and
2. to specify that I am looking for a solution that does not require
   utilizing a specific shell, which the OSGEO4W installation seems to
   require.

Can anybody recommend a certain installation or procedure for installing GDAL Python bindings on Windows 7 or above?

Comment: Try  Christoph Gohlke's [gdal](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal)

Comment: The second answer (same site that @gene is referring to) in the question you posted gives a good alternative. I've used the binaries from [here](http://www.gisinternals.com/stable.php) in the past, which can [even be used in conjunction with ArcGIS's Python if you wish](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74524/how-to-run-ogr-in-arcgis-scripts/74534#74534). Unfortunately it looks like my original links are broken though.

Comment: Please note that it is not helpful for the discoverability of good answers to duplicate questions every couple of years. You can [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw attention to the original question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with it. I have found the GDAL that gets installed with QGIS to be quite useable as utilities. For software development I use the GisInternals http://www.gisinternals.com/ install to match my version of Visual Studio. Either will give you the binaries to use the tools but the GisInternals has a good C#/VB.net GDAL library.

Comment: You have 3 simple options:  Answer #1 in the wiki you link to.  Answer #2 in the wiki  or grab the binaries from the excellent GIS Internals site (see my addition to the wiki for the sake of completeness or follow Michael's link in the comment above).  In each case, download and start the installer, then follow the on-screen instructions.  It is as easy as that.  If you are downloading GDAL binaries rather than using OSGEO4W, just make sure the binary has been compiled against your version of Python (release and 32 or 64 bit) and whatever version of MSVC your machine has installed.